# Zeppelin in EMR Cluster not listing Catalog tables in AWS glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I want to use AWS Glue Data Catalog as the Metastore for Spark SQL. I have launched EMR cluster through AWS console [as instructed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html).

I am able to see all the Glue catalog tables from spark-shell but not from Zeppelin.

Is there any properties need to set in Zeppelin properties configurations??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We just hit this issue as well - we could access AWS Glue tables via Spark shell, but not via Zeppelin.
This could be an issue with Zeppelin - let's hope it'll be addressed shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMR 5.9.0 has just been released (only 9 hours later!) - it should work for you.

Relevant documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-components.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

Comment: @Jagadeesh do you have some example code using glue data catalog as the metastore for sparrk SQL? I'm trying to do this from pyspark to load a dataframe in pyspark